# Migrations Tool Problem Trinity! Help!

Tags: seed

who is familiar with the Iota migration tool for Trinity? If I made a mistake during the migration and put my Iota Token in there, who is responsible for it? Probably me? Or? But, but I didn't read anything about the migration tool that said somewhere that if you make a mistake, you can't get your tokens back at all?! And they are definitely gone! If I had read that I would have doubted the migrations if I do this! I have no guarantees. And I think it should have gone into more detail. At least I would have expected goodwill! And that the IF really helps somehow! But so simply nothing lets you sit! I am very disappointed with the Discord team!Man has not even brought an emergency exit for such cases into the tool! The specialists who created this could have thought of it! What should I do? Complain? Any suggestions???

Comment: The migration tool is trying to be as foolproof as possible. In particular, it forces you to save your seedvault and to write down or elsewhere store your new seed. Obviously, you cannot make anything foolproof enough, as the universe will compete in creating bigger fools. That being said, what exactly did you do to lose your tokens? Run the tool and then format your hard drive without backing up your  seed vault?

Comment: And remember that cryptocurrencies are anonymous. If you lose your keys/seed, you lose your money. It does not matter if it is a wallet or a migration tool.

Comment: Hi i did a Migration!

Comment: And the tool finally indicated that everything is in order! It was migrated

Comment: I created the first seed in the trinity wallet and entered it in the migration tool. Then I wasn't sure if I did it right. Then I created a new seed. and also entered in the migration tool! I printed and saved one of them

Comment: and also entered in the migration tool! I printed and saved one of them. And because others probably forgot. Because I thought it will be deleted automatically.

Comment: But apparently he accepted the first one and I saved the second one. That's the only way I can imagine it, I wasn't sure! And now I'm probably the only one on earth who has put his Miota tokens in the migration tool !?

Comment: How embarrassing! I can not believe it. 2 Gi. just away or what ???? What should I do?
Or maybe I couldn't transfer the first seed to the Trinity wallet.

Comment: Because I printed out the second seed! And then of course have nothing from the first seed! Or? And I also feel very tired and unfocused!
All too much for me! My nice tokens !!!

Comment: Do you still have the migration tool installed? It provides you a migration status page where you can download a logfile of your migrations. That should help to find out which address was actually used and you can check whether that address shows up with your seed in Trinity.

Comment: Also, in case you migrated the same seed twice, and IF did not get in contact with you, they would not have performed any of the two migrations but asked for KYC. In that case, your tokens should still be on the original seed (if not stolen meanwhile).